# mongo db query with group by and where

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to convert this sql query to mongo db query:

```
select * from ( 
select x, count(*) as CNT_T from table 
group by 1 ) aa where aa.Total = aa.CNT_T;
```

I can do the group by (as below) but i don't know how to match the aa.CNT_T with aa.Total after doing the group by.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: { x: "$x" },
               count: { $sum: 1 } } }
])
```

Thanks..

Comment: Is it possible that the `Total` column is missing from the inner select? Also some group by condition or something perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is the match element

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { $group: { _id: { x: "$x" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  { $match: { count: { $eq: 1 } } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query appears little incomplete to me since the `Total` field seems to be missing from the list of columns returned by the inner `SELECT`. Also, there is no `GROUP` being done so I am not certain about what exactly you want to do here.

Using MongoDB v3.6 and bigger, however, you can do something like this using [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which allows you to compare several fields inside the same document:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$x",
        docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$docs" // flatten the result array
}, {
    $match: {
        $expr: { $eq: ["$total", "$count"] } // apply the filter that you're after
    }
}])
```